# How to revert IntellijIDEA 2019 "run" view/tool window console output to older, classic layout

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a maven project which I build in IntellijIDEA using maven tool window. Console output is shown in run tool window. In previous Intellij versions run window presented full console output all the time, but in the new version there are "bookmarks" on the left and there is shown only a piece of console output connected with currently selected bookmark. By default when the build fails there is shown console output from the last bookmark and I have to manually search for parent bookmark and click on it in order to see more console output which gives me information about what really happened.

I would like to have the old view where full console output is presented all the time, because it is more convenient for me. How to revert to run tool window layout similar to layout existing in older Intellij versions ex. 2017.3?

[image: IntellijIdea 2019 run tool window]

As you can see this console output is not descriptive enought. I have to click on user-service to see more after each failed build. But it still doesn't show me everything. To see everything i have to click on parent of user-service (which is invisible on the picture because it is on the top of the scrollable "bookmark list").

In IntellijIDEA 2017.3 it looked like this:
[image]

If it is not possible to revert to the old view maybe it is possible to change this view behaviour to be more convenient for me. For example to show console output of the parent of all packages when build fails instead of showing output of one of the children.

Comment: You can see the same full output when selecting the root node in the left view. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: See also a related request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217959 Would you also like for the output to stay with the full maven goal output until the build process is completed?

Comment: @Andrey I know I can. But I don't want to click it manually after each failed build. What is more I want to keep things simple and I don't need these bookmarks at all. Bookmarks might be a problem when you want to give someone unfamiliar with new Intellij recruitment task to do in a short amount of time. He might have a problem determining where to click to see the reason of failing build. And he could fail not because he is weak at programming, but because tool is not intuitive enought.

Comment: @Andrey  But thanks for link to this request. It is related to my problem. If they accept it, it will partially solve my problem.